# Need Help using Groupby and Join together in Query Statement for MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

I have two models: Departments and Invoice.

```
public partial class Invoice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int VendorId { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public partial class Department
{  
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Departments { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to group by Departments and list total price per Department. I may be almost there with but leaning towards totally lost so any help would be appreciated.

For example:

- Foo - $135
- Bar - $450

What I have now but I am lost with the select portion of statement:

```
var deptGroup = content.Departments
            .Join(content.Invoices, d => d.Id, i => i.DepartmentID, (d, i) => new { Department = d, Invoice = i })
            .GroupBy(d => d.Department.Departments)
            .OrderBy(d => d.Key);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need to select the sum of the invoice prices for each group:

```
var deptGroup = content.Departments
        .Join(content.Invoices, d => d.Id, i => i.DepartmentID, (d, i) => new { Department = d, Invoice = i })
        .GroupBy(d => d.Department.Departments)
        .OrderBy(d => d.Key)
        .Select(d => new
        {
            DepartmentName = d.Key,
            TotalPrice = d.Sum(i => i.Price)
        };
```

It's worth noting that you shouldn't need to use your own joins and groupings for this, though, since each Department already has a collection of invoices on it:

```
var deptGroup = content.Departments
        .Select(d => new
        {
            DepartmentName = d.Departments,
            TotalPrice = d.Invoices.Sum(i => i.Price)
        })
        .OrderBy(d => d.DepartmentName);
```

Comment: Thanks! Both ways worked, I did have to move the .OrderBy in second one above the .Select in order for it to work.

Comment: Figured out the .Orderby in second solution.  Should be }).Orderby(d =>d.DepartmentName);

Comment: Oh, yup, sorry about that. Fixed.